# Передать id на второй курсор в активности Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext, cursor

Здравствуйте еще раз, вот какой вопрос есть курсор через который я вывожу в лист вью данные, по клику на один из полей лист вью мне должно вывести данные на следующую активность, пытаюсь передать данные через intent и bundle - ничего не получается. Может кто то мне показать как передать id на вторую активити, и во второй активити вывести данные по этому id ? Пожалуйста.

Вот как пытаюсь передавать:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history_database_request);
        DatabaseOpenHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getBaseContext());
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] from = { HistoryColumns.REQUEST, BaseColumns._ID };
        final Cursor c = sqliteDB.query(History.TABLE_NAME, from, null, null, null, null, null);
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
        final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list,
                c, from, to);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

                c.moveToPosition(position);
                int rowId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                Uri outURI = Uri.parse(BaseColumns._ID + rowId);
                Intent outData = new Intent();
                outData.setData(outURI);
                outData.setClass(RequestHistoryListActivity.this, HistoryResponseActivity.class);
                startActivity(outData);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Вот как пытаюсь принимать:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.histiry_database_response);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int id = extras.getInt("id");
    DatabaseOpenHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getBaseContext());
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] from = { HistoryColumns.RESPONSE, id };
    final Cursor c = sqliteDB.query(History.TABLE_NAME, from, null, null, null, null, null);
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
    final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list,
            c, from, to);
    EditText lv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    lv.setText(c.getString(0));
}
```

}

Не работает, есть предложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял у вас запрос неправильный

Должно быть что-то вроде

```
String[] from = { HistoryColumns.RESPONSE }; // только наверно правильнее projection обозвать
Cursor c = sqliteDB.query(History.TABLE_NAME, 
from, 
BaseColumns._ID + "="+id, 
null, 
null, 
null, 
null);
```

И еще какой-то непонятный Uri у вас  (еще раз напомню в самом методе OnItemClick есть id, его же можно и использовать, т.е. int rowId=(int)id)

```
Uri outURI = Uri.withAppendedUri(History.CONTENT_URI,Lond.toString(rowId));
```

Хотя он вам вообще не нужен судя по тому как вы берете данные
Вам нужно что-то вроде

```
intent.putExtras("id",rowId);
```

ps. могут быть в методах опечатки, по памяти писал

Answer (score 1):

снова ты? =) мне стыдно за твой вопрос =)

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

        c.moveToPosition(position);
        int rowId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        Uri outURI = Uri.parse(BaseColumns._ID + rowId);
        Intent outData = new Intent();
        outData.setData(outURI);
        outData.setClass(RequestHistoryListActivity.this, HistoryResponseActivity.class);
        startActivity(outData);
        finish();
    }
```

шо это такое? =)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HistoryResponseActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("id", rowId);
startActivity(intent);
```

как-то так, не понятно кого ты хочешь передать